# Gson cannot deserialize same string it created?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gson

I have a HashMap<Picture, String> with Picture being a data-class I created in kotlin. I save the HashMap into the SharedPreferences using `gson.toJson(hashmap)` and this works fine. But when I try to deserialize the very same string (I checked) into the HashMap<Picture, String> again, it fails with a weird error.

This is the Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 3 path $.
```

This is the string for reference:

```json
{
   "Picture(image_url\u003dhttps://nftmintapp.infura-ipfs.io/ipfs/QmZnbgRFCvqXeahD37vaRANjPiyF9oCC2aWw1TwHat8SaU, creator_name\u003dmarkus, creator_address\u003d0x0, image_name\u003dethOS3, additional_url\u003dhttps://google.com)":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
```

The String I save in reference to the String is a Bytearray that I convert to string using `Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.NO_WRAP)`.

I assumed that gson would be able to de-serialize anything it serialized itself, has anybody ever encountered this?

Answer (score 1):

The JSON specification only allows strings as property names of JSON objects. Gson works around this by simply calling the `toString()` function on Map keys and serializing that as JSON property names. However, for deserialization it uses the standard JSON deserialization logic.

For simple Map keys such as `String` or `Int` this works just fine, but for complex key types, such as the `Picture` class in your case, this leads to undesired behavior.

The solution is to either

- restructure your code so it uses a `Map<String, ...>` and for example stores the picture data as part of the `Picture` class as well, or have a data class which contains the picture data and the `Picture` object
- or to
  use [`GsonBuilder.enableComplexMapKeySerialization()`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#enableComplexMapKeySerialization()), see also the [user guide](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Maps-Examples) for additional information

In case you already have released a version of your app with this faulty JSON serialization logic and you want to preserve backward compatibility, you will have to write a [`JsonDeserializer`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html) (or [`TypeAdapterFactory`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory.html), but that is a bit more complicated) which tries to deserialize this faulty JSON value.